# Dojo doesn't have the util folder necessary to build

Tags: cordova, dojo

I'm trying to make a dojo mobile specific build, and the documentation states to use one of the profiles listed in the dojo/util/buildscripts/profiles. But I don't have this directory (util) under the dojo folder... Am I missing something really obvious?

Nota : I'm really newbie in this field, I'd like to try out dojo with phonegap, but get stuck on this very first phase.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, just a heads up on this Android bug that may screw up your use of Dojo. Long story short, you'll need to build Dojo into a single file for it to work properly on Android. http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/faq#i-can-t-seem-to-run-dojo-mobile-pages-on-android-devices-when-using-libraries-like-phonegap-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download **Dojot Toolkit SDK** at the bottom of the [download page](http://dojotoolkit.org/download/) titled as *Source*.

Or grab Dojo from one of version control systems:

- subversion: http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/
- git: https://github.com/dojo

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have looked in there first